# Ruby on rails change local on onchange event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, locale

I declared as onchange event as follows

```
:onchange=>"$(this).format( {format:\"#,###.00\", locale:\"se\"} );
```

I want to replace locale `<%= I18n.locale %>` to this which I ve use in java script . How to replace the above by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
:onchange=>"$(this).format( {format:\"#,###.00\", locale:\"#{I18n.locale}\"} );
```